# Stokes' theorem applied to a cylinder constraint to the first quadrant

Tags: calculus, 3d, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am helping a friend to solve a calculus list. I have solved all the questions, except, this one.

Should you know how to solve, please, let me know!

Solve $\int_C \vec F \cdot dr$ by Stokes theorem, where $\vec F =(xz,xy,y^2)$. $C$ is the border of the surface of the cylinder $z = 4-x^2$, bounded by the planes $x=2, y=3$  on the first octant.

I know that:

[image]

[image]

Now I am facing problems to find a normal vector for making this integral easy to solve.

I know that most likely it is $r = i + j + k$.

However, I have no idea how to confirm that. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You have not given all the boundary of the surface yet. The picture shows just the first octant, but the words do not say that. Presumably you know how to find the normal vector to a cylinder. It certainly is not a constant vector.

Comment: That is all the information I have! I just translated from Portuguese, however, that is all that they gave me!

Comment: I have thought of applying cylindrical coordinates, however, the cylinder is not centered on the center. With cylindrical coordinates, we can assume that the normal vector is perpendicular, and easy to find.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates are not good for parabolic cylinders. How do you find a normal vector to a level surface $f(x,y,z)=c$? And how do you do surface integrals over a general surface?

Comment: Sorry, I did not undestand your question? \z=4-x^2

Comment: Maybe this problem is ill-posed

Comment: it is " The picture shows just the first octant" as you noticed.

Comment: You will find literally dozens of similar questions answered on this site. Have you looked?

Comment: In fact I am new here, I have seen aftermath that there are dozens of questions like that. I will take a look later. If anyone can answer directly, that would be great. Thanks!.

Comment: Do you know how to parameterize the surface $S$ whose boundary is the closed curve $C$ in the picture you posted? That's a good starting point...

Comment: Your computation of curl seems off. (Check the middle term.)

Comment: Thanks guys for the support! solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize the parabolic cylinder surface as,

$r(x,y) = (x, y, 4-x^2)$ and $r'_x \times r'_y = (2x, 0, 1)$

$Curl \vec F = \nabla \times \vec F = (2y, x, y)$

So applying Stokes' thoerem,

$\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \vec n \ dS \  = \int_0^3 \int_0^2 (2y, x, y) \cdot (2x, 0, 1) \ dx \ dy $

Comment: Thanks! That was awesome man!